# Examples of inhabitants of a Boolean vector space and operations in the space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the following quotation (from: http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/edward.grefenstette/GrefenstetteTFDS.pdf):

> We first must consider the vector space used to model the boolean truth values of $\mathbb{B}$. Coecke et al. (2010) suggest, as boolean vector space, the space $B$ with the basis $\\{\top, \bot \\}$, where $\top = [1 \quad 0]^{\top}$ is interpreted as `true’, and $\bot = [0 \quad 1]^{\top}$ as ‘false’.

What are the inhabitants of this vector space $\mathbb{B}$? Can you give some examples of inhabitants and how the vectorial operations $+$ and $\cdot$ operate in the vector space?

Comment: Vector space over what field? $F_2$? $\Bbb R$? $\Bbb C$? something else? And what is $\Bbb B$? Obviously, they choose a two-dimensional vector space to represent the truth values, but why is not clear. At a bare mimimum. if $F_2$ is the field, then there are four "inhabitants": $$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}. \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ What interpretation should be given to the other two elements is not clear.